# cut words from csv file to text file only if the second field in csv is yes

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have the following csv file, `file.csv`:

```
1,yes,yes,customer1
2,no,yes,customer5
3,yes,yes,customer11
4,no,no,customer14
5,yes,no,customer15
6,yes,yes,customer21
7,no,yes,customer34
8,no,yes,customer89
```

I want to convert the csv file to the following format, `new_file.txt`

the first field and the four field should be taken from the csv line only if the second field in the csv is "yes"

```
Line Number 1 Customer customer1
Line Number 3 Customer customer11
Line Number 5 Customer customer15
Line Number 6 Customer customer21
```

Please advice how to convert the csv to txt (new_file.txt)  with awk , sed , or perl one liner , etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes it:

```
$ awk -F, '$2=="yes" {printf "Line number %d customer %s\n", $1, $4}' file
Line number 1 customer customer1
Line number 3 customer customer11
Line number 5 customer customer15
Line number 6 customer customer21
```

It sets the comma as field separator and checks if the 2nd field is exactly "yes". In that case, prints the desired output.

In case you want this checking to be not case sensitive, you have two options:

Use regex:

```
awk -F, '$2~/^[yY][eE][sS]$/'
```

Use `IGNORECASE`:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $2=="yes"' a
```

All together:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $2=="yes" {printf "Line number %d customer %s\n", $1, $4}' file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
1,yes,yes,customer1
2,no,yes,customer5
3,YES,yes,customer11
4,no,no,customer14
5,yeS,no,customer15
6,yEs,yes,customer21
7,no,yes,customer34
8,no,yes,customer89
$ awk -F, '$2~/^[yY][eE][sS]$/ {print $2}' a
yes
YES
yeS
yEs
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $2=="yes" {print $2}' a
yes
YES
yeS
yEs
```

See [Gawk manual --> 3.6 Case Sensitivity in Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html) for further info.

Comment: another question - how to update your code in case the second field is yes or YES or Yes or YEs .. etc ?  ( because the second field could be any combination of y/Y/e/E/s/S

Comment: @maihabunash Check update for ignore case... and thanks for +1 :)

Comment: @Jidder To me it, and in this specific case, it is more clear than `print "Line number", $1, "customer", $4`. But both options are fine.

Answer (score 2):

Perl one liner:

```
perl -F, -lanE 'say "Line number $F[0] customer $F[3]" if $F[1] eq "yes"' file
Line number 1 customer customer1
Line number 3 customer customer11
Line number 5 customer customer15
Line number 6 customer customer21
```

**Switches**:

- `-F`: `split()` pattern for `-a` switch
- `-l`: Enable line ending processing
- `-a`: Splits the line on space and loads them in an array `@F`
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-E`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line like `-e`,  but enables all optional features